# Joomla can't find component

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

And this is the message I get when I navigate to joomla/dev/v01/index.php?option=com_helloworld

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's your xml file? Where's you controller? Where's your modal? Have you read the tutorial on the Joomla docs on how to create a basic Hello World component?

Comment: @Lodder This is the doc I'm starting with: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Is there a tutorial I should go through first?

Comment: This is the correct link but if you scroll down to where it says **Packaging an installation zip file **, you will see all the requires files that are needed to successfully install a basic component.

Comment: @Lodder So `index.php?option=com_helloworld` shouldn't actually show anything until the component is installed?

Answer (score 1):

You must register your component in the table #__extensions

You can do this manually:

```
INSERT INTO #__extensions 
(`name`, `type`, `element`, `client_id`, `access`, `manifest_cache`, `params`) 
VALUES 
('com_helloword', 'component', 'com_helloword', 1, 0, '{"name":"com_helloword","type":"component","creationDate":"2014-02-01","author":"Me","copyright":"Copyright (C) 2014. All rights reserved.","authorEmail":"me@email.com","authorUrl":"http:\\/\\/http:\\/\\/www.mysite.com.br\\/","version":"1.0.0","description":"","group":""}', '{}');
```

or you can create the standard xml installation...

Answer (score 1):

Create proper XML file with component details and use system `Discover` option to install component. Its easiest way and doesn't require to mess in the database. Here is example of an [component xml file](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component#File_Details). Here you can find a whole tutorial on [creating Joomla! components](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction).